# haskell: Repeat multiplicative sequencer on finite list of infinite lists

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, infinite

Given a finite list of infinite lists, or alternatively, an infinite list of finite lists, I'd like to apply a multiplicative operator `(~>)` or `(~~>)` or `(>*>)` if you will that obeys the distributive property:

```
[[a], [b], [c]] >*> [[d], [e]] == [[a, d], [a, e], [b, d], [b, e], [c, d], [c, e]]
```

This also applies to `(~>)`, and for `(~~>)` the transposed representation.

I'd then like to "repeat" this multiplicative operator "forever``

Here are my attempts, all of which due to co-dependency (I think) end up in stack overflow or never terminates.

Example 1:

```
import Data.Maybe(listToMaybe)
import Control.Monad(liftM2)

type A = [[Int]]

a :: A
a = [[1]]

-- Building finite lists of infinite lists:
(~>) :: A -> A -> A
(~>) = liftM2 (++)

forever1 :: A -> A
forever1 p = p ~> forever1 p

forever2 :: A -> A
forever2 p = forever2 p ~> p
```

Example 2:

```
-- Building infinite lists of finite lists:
(~~>) p q = mx q p ++ mx p q
    where innerLen = maybe 0 length . listToMaybe
          mx a = map (concatMap $ replicate $ innerLen a)

forever3 :: A -> A
forever3 p = p ~~> forever3 p

forever4 :: A -> A
forever4 p = forever4 p ~~> p

{-
forever1 p = do
    x <- p
    y <- do
        x' <- p
        y' <- do
            ...
    return $ x ++ y

forever1 p =
    p >>= \x1 -> p >>= \x2 -> p >>= ... >>= \xn -> return concat [x1, x2, ... xn]
-}
```

Example 3:

```
u = undefined

type ActionFn a = a -> (Action a, a)
data Action a = None | A { act :: ActionFn a }
newtype Program a = P { actions :: [Action a] }

(>>>) :: Action a -> Action a -> Action a
(>>>) None q = q
(>>>) (A f) g = A $ \a -> let (h, b) = f a in (h >>> g, b)

(>*>) :: Program a -> Program a -> Program a
(>*>) (P ps) (P qs) = P $ zipWith (>>>) (mul qs ps) (mul ps qs)
    where mul other = concatMap (replicate $ length other)

basic :: ActionFn a -> Program a
basic = P . return . A

idle :: Program a
idle = basic $ \a -> (None, a)

forever5 :: Program a -> Program a
forever5 p = p >*> forever5 p

testF5 = map (const "x") $ actions $ forever5 idle
```

The lists aren't actually made up of `Int`s but rather functions `a -> a`.

Is my problem possible to solve in some way? If so - how?
Or is it not possible?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question, because of the initial example with the "distributive" equation for `>*>`, whose left hand side involves finite lists of singleton lists—not finite lists of infinite lists or vice-versa.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, should have been more specific...
If you do: `forever1 [[1]]` then it is building a finite list of infinite lists using `~>`. `forever` is like repeat, but does it multiplicatively, so it becomes an infinite power.

Anyways, I'm now quite certain that this is not possible under any circumstance, but I haven't the words to formulate a proper formal answer... Perhaps you do?

`forever1 [[1]]` will cause stack overflow.